# pls-00642 local collection types not allowed in sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I understand that exists a lot of material about this, but I still cannot make this work properly. The code above is my last attempt. The problem is I have duplicate and sometimes **triplicate** records in a table

What I need:

- get repeated records
- "save" the minor sequencial of each repeated record (first to be created, should be maintained)
- delete other records

*I could not make group by... having count > 1 using sequential, cause sequentials do not repeat

```
DECLARE

TYPE SEQ_HISTORICO IS TABLE OF SIA.HISTORICO_ESCOLAR.NUM_SEQ_HISTORICO%TYPE;

V_MANTER SEQ_HISTORICO; -- least sequential, should be mantained

V_EXCLUIR SEQ_HISTORICO; -- others, to be deleted


BEGIN

   WITH 
   DUPLICADAS AS
   (
              select he.seq_historico,
                   he.cod_disciplina,
                   di.nom_disciplina,
                   pa.nom_fantasia,
                   he.cod_situacao_aluno_turma
              from ow.historico_escolar he
             inner join ow.periodo_academico pa on he.num_seq_periodo_academico =
                                                    pa.num_seq_periodo_academico
             inner join ow.disciplina di on he.cod_disciplina = di.cod_disciplina
             where he.seq_aluno_curso = '424242'
               and he.cod_situacao_aluno_turma = 'IS'

   )
   SELECT LEAST(nseq_historico) INTO V_MANTER FROM DUPLICADAS;

END;
```

ERROR: pls-00642 local collection types not allowed in sql statement

Should I use pls_integer?

Comment: You could `BULK COLLECT INTO V_MANTER`, but I'm not sure you meant `LEAST()` - perhaps `MIN()`; but then if you're only getting back a single value to keep you don't need a collection there. You seem to be identifying one `num_seq_aluno_curso`/`cod_situacao_aluno_turma` paris at a time, at the moment anyway.... But are the duplicates in that table, or in the ones you're joining to - otherwise why join at all? And why are you using PL/SQL at all, instead of just directly deleting the duplicates?

Comment: is not a single value... is the min sequential for each group of repeated discipline

Comment: Well, there will be a single min value for each group, but your query is only looking at one group - isn't it? Perhaps you hope to remove the `where` clause later, but at the moment you'd still only get a single value from the query - assuming you did mean `min()` not `least()`, which doesn't tell you anything with a single argument; and it wouldn't necessarily relate to a duplicate. Maybe adding sample data and more about what you want to achieve would help point you to a different approach.

Comment: *"is the min sequential for each group of repeated discipline"* Then you need MIN() and a GROUP BY clause. It's hard for us to understand what you're trying to achieve by code alone. It would be helpful if you provided some sample input data and required outcome derived from that input.

Comment: ok, thank you, i'm working on this

Answer (score 1):

The error is trying to tell you that you can't `SELECT...INTO...` an instance of a type declared in PL/SQL. In this case the problem arises because of

```
SELECT LEAST(nseq_historico) INTO V_MANTER FROM DUPLICADAS
```

Here, `V_MANTER` is of type `SEQ_HISTORICO` which is defined in a PL/SQL block.

You can, however, `BULK COLLECT` into a PL/SQL collection, but in order to use the `MIN` function you'll need to add a GROUP BY clause. It appears from your comments that you want to group by HISTORICO_ESCOLAR.COD_DISCIPLINA, so putting this together we get:

```
WITH DUPLICADAS AS (select he.seq_historico,
                           he.cod_disciplina,
                           di.nom_disciplina,
                           pa.nom_fantasia,
                           he.cod_situacao_aluno_turma
                      from ow.historico_escolar he
                      inner join ow.periodo_academico pa
                        on he.num_seq_periodo_academico = pa.num_seq_periodo_academico
                      inner join ow.disciplina di
                        on he.cod_disciplina = di.cod_disciplina
                      where he.seq_aluno_curso = '424242' and 
                            he.cod_situacao_aluno_turma = 'IS')
SELECT COD_DISCIPLINA, MIN(SEQ_HISTORICO) 
  BULK COLLECT INTO V_MANTER
  FROM DUPLICADAS
  GROUP BY COD_DISCIPLINA
```

Best of luck.